# React - native .I can't import images, says it's not present on the way

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When I try to import any file other than .js extension, it gives error saying I can't find the file. I'm trying to import an image right now. Auto complete does not find the image, but finds the folder. If I type the name of the image manually it gives error when making the bundle.

version react-native 0.60.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEH70.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use it like that you can add an `index.js` file inside of your image folder to export all your images, like this:

**images/index.js**

```js
import login from './ImageLogin.jpg';

export default { login };
```

**login.js**

```js
import images from '../images';
```

and then

```js
<Image source={images.login}/>
```

Comment: You can explain Image what tag or component it is

Comment: @RichWarrior This is React Native, not Reactjs only https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html